# Microsoft Graph - Access Deneined when accessing to calendar events with specifiying user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am working on creating application which uses Microsoft Graph API to access to calendar events for the users that belongs to an organization.

There is no issue getting event using below endpoint
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events

However, when accessing to below end point cause 403 error.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/calendar/events

403 - Forbidden
{"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."}}

So far I have below:

1. Application is registed to Aure with granting

   - Application.ReadWrite.All
   - Calendars.ReadWrite
   - offline_access
   - User.ReadWrite.All
2. Have logic to retrieve the access / refresh token.
3. When the access token is decoded, below scoes are availalbe
   "scp": "Application.ReadWrite.All Calendars.ReadWrite User.ReadWrite.All profile openid email"

Others:

1. Below endpoints work

- https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
- https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

2. Below endpoints errors with access denied

- https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/calendars

3. I also tried using User Principal Name instead of ID but it didn't make any difference.

Can someone please help why I am not able to access to the user calendar / events when specifying the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message showed `Access is denied`, we can understand that your account doesn't have enough permission to call that api(querying others' calendar events). Since the request calling only related with the access token, no matter whether you have an admin role or not. So let's assume whether you want other users to sign in your app and then they are able to query your calendar events.

According to your description, your token contained `scp` claim, so I'm sure you are using the delegate permission, which means you signed in and calling api on behalf yourself. And this may be the reason why the access is denied.

[image]

We can see the permissions in the screenshot above, I think the application permission type can solve your issue. Using permission type means the api calling is executed by your application itself, but not on behalf of some user. So the application can query any users' calendar events in your tenant.

Using application permission required you to assign application api permission like screenshot below.

[image]

Then if you are just testing via tools like postman, using [request below](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret) to generate access token:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=sampleCredentia1s
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

If are composing an asp.net core application and trying to call graph api via graph sdk, follow [code snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request) below:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "aad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var events = await graphClient.Users["{user_id}"].Events
    .Request()
    .Header("Prefer","outlook.timezone=\"Pacific Standard Time\"")
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you. I was using grant_type=authorization_code and changing to grant_type=client_credentials start working for other users... I haven't been able to figure out why using grant_type=authorization_code does not all access to allow users (but only allow access for myself)

Only Calendars.ReadWrite / Application permission was required.

Comment: the reason for getting access denied issue is that you are using delegate api permission but not application permission. using `grant_type=authorization_code` required you to sign in first to get the `auth code`, this means you are using delegate permission. Just like I said above, you may not willing to see upon sign in, a user can query any other's calendar event. So you need to use `grant_type=client_credentials`. This won't require you to sign in right? That's because this method obtain access token on behalf of the application. In other words, it has a "bigger" permission than only a user

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I thought we needed to be able to recieve the refresh token to refresh the access token, but it seems that the Access Token URL in Microsoft does not require having refresh token. When I worked on for Google, we need to use the refersh token, so that where I wen to the wrong direction...

Comment: you used `grant_type=client_credentials` and this kind of flow doesn't have a refresh token for it. Only auth code flow has refresh token. You shouldn't and can't use refresh token in your screnario.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are trying to access another user calendar events, make sure you have Calendars.Read delegated permission , you can check what type of permission you have in azure portal -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/migrate-azure-ad-graph-configure-permissions?tabs=http%2Cupdatepermissions-azureadgraph-powershell